# Same view controller UI, different functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller whose UI is the identical between 2 classes, but the functionality is different. One of the classes uses the view controller to add a contact, the other uses it to edit a contact.

Is there a way to "reuse" the layout/view of the view controller while having different classes (add/edit class)?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"AddContact"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddContact *addContact = (AddContact *)navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject;
        addContact.delegate = self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"EditContact"]) {
        EditContact *editContact = (EditContact *)segue.destinationViewController;
        editContact.currentContact = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    }
}
```

The `segue.destinationViewController` is of type `ViewContact` which both `AddContact` and `EditContact` both inherit from. All it does it hold onto the outlets for the textfields that both of its children use.

Unfortunately, the snippet above doesn't work because you can't really typecast parents to their children.

Comment: You could use VC, AddVC (inherits from VC), EditVC (inherits from VC). If the changes are really small, you may even use a var at the beginning to set if it for edit or add.

Comment: Yes use same layout (strictly). To re-use, keep one variable that will say whether you are in that layout for add or edit...

Comment: Inheriting is good, that didn't even occur to me.

Comment: alternatively, you could simply abstract the functionality for adding and editing into separate components and use a single VC. That way you could provide more functionality on the same screen and toggle states

Comment: Agreeing with @DanielGalasko here.  Except for the actual "save" logic, an add function is often an edit function that happens to start with empty fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do is create a single view controller, with a xib included, and add a property like so:

**header file**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CRUD) { //Create, Read, Update, Delete
    CTCreate,
    CTRead

};

@property ( assign, readonly ) CRUD option;
```

And in the initialization of this view controller you'd have something like:

**header**

```
- (id)initWithOption:(CRUD)optionValue;
```

**implentation**

```
- (id)initWithOption:(CRUD)optionValue {
    ...
    option = optionValue;

    return self;

}
```

And in the implementation of this class you'd have if statements where the differences are, like when the user hits saves, should this class insert a new record, add, or update a recorded, edit

Hope this helps :) feel free to ask for more clarification :)p

Comment: I did something similar to this, sorry for never accepting your answer. On a side-note, you look a little bit like John Frusciante.

Comment: Rock on, maybe I do look like him :3 glad you got something working out tho :)